# Using ad-hoc wrapper functions without packaging and without showing in global environment in R(studio)

Tags: r, ide, package, rstudio

Not sure if this is even possible.

I use Rstudio and appreciate having an overview of the objects I'm working with in the Global Environment pane.

However, at the same time, I have some 15 or so simple wrapper functions that are specific to my project, e.g. on various reading and writing functions so that they automate some file management tasks and follow my preferred folder structure; unfortunately, they also clutter that GE view.

I guess I could put them all in a package but I'm quite sure I will not publish it and may not even need many of them beyond this one project.

Is there anything short of bundling them into a package for this kind of three-line functions?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a perfect case for packages, here are two simple intro to creating them with the `devtools` package: [1](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html)
 [2](https://uoftcoders.github.io/studyGroup/lessons/r/packages/lesson/). If you create one, you don't have to put  it on cran, and you can install it from your local folder. I hope you will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always put them into a list:

```
helper_functions <- list(f1 = function1,
                         f2 = function2)
```

Then you can call them by `helper_functions$f2()`.

Example:

```
plus_one <- function(n){
  return(n + 1)
}

plus_two <- function(n){
  return(n + 2)
}


plus <- list(one = plus_one,
             two = plus_two)

plus$two(2)
# 4
```